# Can you plz explain how in the (a) part of a solution to the problem, $2.7 × 10^5$ is approximated to zero?

Tags: approximations

Here is a numerical in my book;

> Observer S reports that an event occurred on the x axis of his reference frame at $x= 3.00\cdot 10^8$ m st time -2.50s. Observer S' and her frame are moving in the positive direc tion of the x axis at a speed of $0.400c$. Further, $x=x'=0$ at $t=0$. What are the (a) spatial and (b) temporal coordinate of the event according to S'?

Now in solving the a part, answer is $2.7\cdot 10^8$ m which is approximated to $0$?
Is it due to a reason that given $x=3\cdot 10^8$ is much larger than the calculated $x'=2.7\cdot 10^5$?

[image]

Comment: If you take $c$ to be $3\times 10^8$ m/s (which is correct to 2 decimal places) then $x'$ becomes exactly $0$.

Comment: Would you plz elaborate it a little more for me.

Comment: The only reason $x'$ is non-zero in the given calculation is that $0.4c$ is taken to be $1.199 \times 10^8$ m/s instead of the slightly less accurate value $1.2 \times 10^8$ m/s. When you see a SR question with values that are nice round multiples of $3 \times 10^8$ then you are probably expected to take $c$ as $3 \times 10^8$ m/s.

Comment: Very sorry to bother you again and thanks for your response. But I meant to say that would you explain how 3 × 10⁸ being correct to two decimal places, makes x’ exactly zero?

Comment: If $c=3 \times 10^8$ then $v = 0.4c = 1.2 \times 10^8$ and $vt = (1.2 \times 10^8) \times 2.50 = 3 \times 10^8$ so $x-vt = 0$.

Comment: Now, I get it. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the answer, $2.7 \times 10^5 $ m is approximated to zero. The reason you can do that is because we are talking about speeds close to the speed of light, and the light would travel that distance in $0.001 $ s. That is negligible to the $2.5 $ s mentioned in the exercise.